# register div redirecting to login page when there are auth errors

Tags: jquery, laravel, validation

I have an index page that has login and sign up on different divs controlled by jQuery.

when there are errors in the registration page the errors the  page loads back to the login page and the login page also shows that it has errors which shouldn't be the case

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="auth-buttons">
        <a class="btn" id="btn-login">Login</a>
        <a class="btn" id="btn-register">Register</a>
    </div>
    <div id="lgn" class="btns">
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login')}}" autocomplete="off">
            @csrf
            @if($errors->any())
            <div class="auth-error">
                <i class="icon-warning-sign"></i>Error:Incorrect password/email.Please try again
            </div>
            @endif
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="reg" class="btns">
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register')}}" autocomplete="off">
            @if (count($errors) > 0)
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <p>{{ $error }}
                </button>
            </p>
            @endforeach
            @endif
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

`jQuery`

```js
$('#reg').hide();
$('#btn-login').click(function () {
    $('#reg').hide();
    $('#lgn').show();
});
$('#btn-register').click(function () {
    $('#lgn').hide();
    $('#reg').show();
});
```

Comment: You have no form actions set...unless you're using AJAX to send the forms?

Comment: i've edited the code,was just simplifying the question @FAKETAXI

Answer (score 0):

I will give full example to show errors for every field:-
There are many way to provide validation to your form in laravel
1) Request method

```html
public function form(Request $request)
{
  $request->validate([
    'field1' => 'require|min|max',
    'fields2' =>'require|min|max' 
  ],
  [
    'field1.require' => 'your msg',
    'field1.max' => 'your msg',
    'field1.min' => 'your msg',,
    'field2.require' => 'your msg',
  ]
  );
}
```

2) By creating separate file using php artisan make:request filename.this file will create into app\html\request folder with authorize,rules methods, you define some more method like message for custom message and attribute method to give different field name.
example :

```html
public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required',
            'pass' => 'required|min:6|max:15'
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'email.required' => 'Email is required',
            'pass.required' => 'Password is required',
            'pass.min' => 'Password must be atleast 6 digit long',
            'pass.max' => 'Password must not be greater than 15 digits'
        ];
    }

    public function attributes()
    {
        return [
            'pass' => 'user password',
            'email' => 'email address',
        ];
    }
```

3) with validator method, to use validator you have to define facade 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\validator;
example:-

```html
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
       'email' => 'required',
       'pass' => 'required|min:6|max:15'
      ], 
      [
       'email.required' => ':attribute is required',
       'pass.required' => 'password is required',
       'pass.min' => 'Password must be atleast 6 digits',
       'pass.max' => 'Password must not be greater than 15 digits'
      ]
     )->validate();
```

lets show erros message in blade
1) in blade make form and show error msg when validation failed  like

```html
<form action="{{route('validation')}}" method="post">
  @csrf
 <div class="form-group"> 
  <label>Email</label>
  @error('email')
  <p style="color:red">{{$message}}</p>
  @enderror
   <input type="email" name="email" value="{{old('email')}}" class="form-control"> 
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label>password</label>
  @error('pass')
   <p style="color:red">{{$message}}</p>
  @enderror
  <input type="password" name="pass" value="{{old('pass')}}" class="form-control">
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
  <input type="file" class="form-control" name="files">
 </div> 

 
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
 </form>
```

2) in controller

```html
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
       'email' => 'required',
       'pass' => 'required|min:6|max:15'
      ], 
      [
       'email.required' => ':attribute is required',
       'pass.required' => 'password is required',
       'pass.min' => 'Password must be atleast 6 digits',
       'pass.max' => 'Password must not be greater than 15 digits'
      ]
     )->validate();
```

if validation failed than it will redirect automatically to blade with error msg and print them.

Comment: the problem is the page shows the validation errors but it first loads to login page first instead of returning to the registration tab

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish between your login and registration errors. You can do this with Error Bags!

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#named-error-bags

The doc is a little bit vague but should give you a good place to start.